# modify URL responses in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a page loading videos from Youtube API V3 and I made a function to filter the videos with a form.

When the videos are filtered, I go back on the same page and show only the videos that fit the query but the response URL is :

http://localhost/Welcome/filterStuffs/cache?side=CT&stuff=smoke

And I would like to have just :

http://localhost/stuffs/cache?side=CT&stuff=smoke

Here is my controller :

```
public function filterStuffs($map) {

// Get videos that match the tags
$stuffs = $this->youtube->getVideosByTags($allVideosIds, $tags);

$data['map'] = $map;
$data['stuffs'] = $stuffs;
$data['contents'] = 'stuffs.php';

// Loading view with updated videos
$this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
}
```

EDIT : My URL is built from this code :

```
echo form_open('Welcome/filterStuffs/'.$map, $attribute);
```

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by replacing :

```
echo form_open('Welcome/filterStuffs/'.$map, $attribute);
```

By :

```
echo form_open('stuffs/filters/'.$map, $attribute);
```

And adding this route in config/route.php :

```
$route['stuffs/filters/cache'] = 'Welcome/filterStuffs/cache';
```

hope this can helped some of you ! :)